# C# JSON parsing vs substring

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, substring, json.net

I have a program that is making web request, then breaking down the response. The content type is JSON, and Im currently treating the response as a string and using substring to decode it.

```
string bidnumber = "buyNowPrice";
int startbid = tradetemp.IndexOf(bidnumber) + 13;
int bidlength = 10;
string bidtemp = tradetemp.Substring(startbid, bidlength);
string endbid = ",";
int endbid2 = bidtemp.IndexOf(endbid);
int bidlength2 = endbid2;
string bidtmp = bidtemp.Substring(0, bidlength2);
long bid = Convert.ToInt64(bidtmp);
```

Im doing this for about 5 variables, and constantly doing it over and over. The question is would using JSON parsing be more efficient (faster) over my current code. Using a JSON parse would make my code cleaner, but speed is priority here.

Comment: How about using the [`dynamic` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), in .NET 4?

Comment: Test it - try it out with several different JSON parsers and compare the speed against your implementation, using representative data.

Comment: @Uwe How exactly does `dynamic` help here?

Comment: What you're doing looks pretty quick.  You could maybe make it faster by converting the string to a char array and keeping indexes instead of creating new substrings.  If your code works for all cases then it is probably faster than JSON, but with JSON you would be able to handle more robust data comming in, and if the source data changes it might be less likely to fail.  I would be really suprised to find JSON parsing being faster than what you are doing.

Comment: Have you measured anything yet?

Comment: @Rawling I've used `dynamic` in the past to parse JSON.

Answer (score 5):

Use JSON parsing. One of the biggest mistakes that you can make as a programmer is to say that speed matters and write long, hideous code because of it. There are a couple problems with this approach.

1. How much does speed matter? If you can eliminate 70% of your written code in exchange for 10ms of performance, is that acceptable? You can't know the tradeoff without implementing a well-written solution and seeing it for yourself.
2. It is not necessarily the things that you think are draining performance that will drain performance. Writing code to be fast doesn't necessarily solve performance problems because you need to *test* its performance.
3. How much headache are you prepared to suffer in exchange for "speed"? Again, you don't know how much speed before you benchmark, but poorly-written code, or just even long and messy code can considerably increase the cost of maintaining your program. Don't underestimate this.

I strongly recommend you use the JSON.NET library included by default in VS 2012. I have used it a fair bit and have been quite impressed overall. It is clean and simple to use. Implement it and then benchmark. I think you'll be impressed.

Comment: In my programs case speed is an absolute must. As small as 10 ms is, it could be the difference between finding what its looking for, or getting beaten to it by another person.

Comment: I still recommend that you implement JSON.NET and benchmark. You need hard data before making such a decision.

Answer (score 4):

You could always try it out and measure the performance compared to your code. But I would recommend you using a JSON parser because this will make your code much more stable. Here's a [`nice comparison`](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) of different JSON serializers for .NET. [ServiceStack's JSON serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) is one of the fastest out there if speed is so much important to you.

Also don't forget to read [`stop rolling your CSV parser`](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp) article.

Answer (score 0):

JSON parsing would definitely be more efficient. It would make your code much cleaner, and it would be just as speedy as you want to. The best thing everyone recommends is using : [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

It's proven to be speedier than the standard C# JavascriptSerializer. JSON.NET makes serializing and deserializing objects a snap, and does it quickly and efficiently.

There's a performance comparison of JSON.NET to regular C# JSON libraries at the bottom of the page.